# Trouble with reading Bitmaps from SD-Card

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, sd

I'm having problems with reading a bitmap file with the SD library. 
I wrote a small header that reads uncompressed 24-bit bitmap files. It works fine when I try it on Windows 10 MingW with fread() instead of SD.read().
On my UNO it only reads the correct offset address, the other parts are garbage.

For a pure red 1x1 px bitmap I get the following expected output on Windows with MingW:

```
Fname: ..\rot.bmp
Offset: 00000036
W * H: 1 * 1
Bit# 24
Cmp: 0
ArraySize: 1
---------------------------
RGB: ff0000
```

Arduino outputs:

```
Fname: rot.bmp
Offset: 00000036
W * H: 0 * 2304
Bit# 58
Cmp: 0
ArraySize: 8
---------------------------
Error while reading BMP file
```

bmp.hpp

```
#ifndef BMP_HEADER
#define BMP_HEADER

#if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA)
#include <SD.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#define BYTE uint8_t
#define WORD uint16_t
#define DWORD uint32_t
#define LONG int32_t
#else
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#endif // defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA)
#pragma pack(2)
typedef struct 
{
  BYTE B;
  BYTE G;
  BYTE R;
} pixel;

typedef struct
{
  WORD bfType;
  DWORD bfSize;
  DWORD bfReserved;
  DWORD bfOffset; //offset to byte array
} bfheader;

typedef struct 
{
  DWORD biSize; //size of this header
  LONG biWidth; //image width
  LONG biHeight;//image height
  WORD biPlanes;
  WORD biBitCount; //color depth in bit per pixel
  DWORD biCompression; //0 for none(RGB mode)
  DWORD biSizeImage; //size of image in byte; may be 0 if biCompression is RGB
  LONG biXPelsPerMeter;
  LONG biYPelsPerMeter;
  DWORD biClrUsed; //palete stuff
  DWORD biClrImportant; //more palete stuff
} biheader;

//returns BGR array of bitmap
//header and biheader are assumed to be allocated upon execution
//returns null if unsuccessful
inline pixel* readBMP(const char* filename, bfheader* header, biheader* infoheader)
{
    #if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA)  
    SDLib::File f = SD.open(filename);
    if(!f) return NULL;
    f.read((uint8_t *)header, sizeof(bfheader)); // read the 14-byte file header
    f.read((uint8_t *)infoheader, sizeof(biheader)); //read the 40-byte info header
    #else
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(f == NULL) return NULL;
    fread(header, sizeof(bfheader), 1, f);
    fread(infoheader, sizeof(biheader), 1, f);
    #endif //defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA)
  if(infoheader->biCompression != 0 || infoheader->biBitCount != 24) //if the file is not RGB encoded or if its not 24bit 
  { 
    #if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA)   
    f.close();
    #else
    fclose(f);
    #endif // defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA)
    return NULL;
  }
  int size = (int) infoheader->biSizeImage/sizeof(pixel); //get byte size of pixel array
  pixel* data = (pixel*) malloc(sizeof(pixel)*size); // allocate
  #if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA)
    f.seek(header->bfOffset); //set file cursor to starting address of RGB array
    f.read((uint8_t *)data, sizeof(uint8_t)*size); // read the rest of the data at once 
    f.close();
  #else
    fseek(f, header->bfOffset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(data, sizeof(pixel), size, f);
    fclose(f);
  #endif //__arm__
  return data;
} 
#endif //BMP_HEADER
```

readbmp_test.ino

```
#include<arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "bmp.hpp"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");
}

void loop() 
{
  char debug[160];
  char rgbdata[8];
  const char* const files[] = {"rot.bmp", "gruen.bmp", "blau.bmp"};
  int files_len = 3;
  bfheader header;
  biheader infoheader;  
  pixel* image;
  for(int i=0; i<files_len; i++)
  {
    image = readBMP(files[i], &header, &infoheader);
    Serial.println("----------------------------");
    sprintf(debug,  "Fname: %s\n"
                "Offset: %08lx\n"
                "W * H: %ld * %ld\n"
                "Bit# %u\n"
                "Cmp: %lu\n"
                "ArraySize: %lu\n"
                "---------------------------\n", 
                  files[i], 
                  header.bfOffset, 
                  infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, 
                  infoheader.biBitCount, 
                  infoheader.biCompression, 
                  infoheader.biSizeImage/sizeof(pixel));
    Serial.print(debug);
    if(image != NULL)
    {

      for(unsigned j=0; j<infoheader.biSizeImage/sizeof(pixel); j++)
      {
        sprintf(rgbdata, "%02x %02x %02x", image[j].R, image[j].G, image[j].B);
        Serial.println(rgbdata);
      }
    }else{
        sprintf(debug, "Error while reading BMP file\n");
        Serial.print(debug);
    }
    free(image);
  }
}
```

main.cpp //MingW Windows Test

```
#if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA)  //arduino compiler wants to run this main?
#else
#include<stdio.h>
#include "bmp.hpp"

int main(const int argc, const char** argv)
{
    if(argc < 2) return -1;

    bfheader header;
    biheader infoheader;
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {      
        pixel* image = readBMP(argv[i], &header, &infoheader);
        if(image != NULL)
        {
            printf("Fname: %s\n"
                    "Offset: %08x\n"
                    "W * H: %d * %d\n"
                    "Bit# %d\n"
                    "Cmp: %d\n"
                    "ArraySize: %d\n"
                    "---------------------------\n", 
                    argv[i], 
                    header.bfOffset, 
                    infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, 
                    infoheader.biBitCount, 
                    infoheader.biCompression, 
                    infoheader.biSizeImage/sizeof(pixel));    
            for(int j=0; j<infoheader.biSizeImage/sizeof(pixel); j++)
            {
                printf("RGB: %02x%02x%02x\n", image[j].R, image[j].G, image[j].B);
            }
        }else{
                printf("Error while reading BMP file\n");
                return 1;
        }
        free(image);
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

I'm really stuck on this, I actually rewrote it a couple times already.
I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: print out the number of bytes read with `file.read` (return value). try to use `readBytes` instead of `read` if the count of read bytes doesn't match the expected size

Comment: @Juraj I tried with with readBytes and read. Same result: The first read returns the expected 14 bytes. The second only returns 2 instead of the expected 40.

Comment: print the structure as bytes with println(b, HEX), to see the raw bytes to check their position in struct fields

Comment: How would I do so? `Serial.println(*infoheader, HEX);` results in `'HardwareSerial::println(biheader&, int)'`

Comment: I tried  with`for(int i=0; i<sizeof(biheader); i++)` The output seems to match the hex dump of the file. I put a a hexdump of the bitmap and the output on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YkhkXP8z)

Comment: it could be a problem of printf. you have %d and that reads only two bytes on Arduino. print the values without sprintf as Serial.println(number)

Comment: Hint: Start by correcting the header read. The sizeof is wrong. Use sizeof the struct and not the pointer. Use the same sizeof for both variants.

Comment: @MikaelPatel thanks for your input. I fixed that part, but I still have problems.

Comment: @Juraj Your tipp with the sprintf was pretty good. I turned on all warnings during compile and saw that the datatypes didn't match the format strings. I fixed that and now my header information is displayed correctly. There is sadly still a problem left as the pure red bitmap displays false pixel values: `sprintf(rgbdata, "%02x %02x %02x", image[j].R, image[j].G, image[j].B);
        Serial.println(rgbdata);` displays: `c5 00 00` dispite the bitmap not containing C5 at all.

Answer (score 1):

`f.read((uint8_t *)infoheader, sizeof(infoheader));`

should be

`f.read((uint8_t *)infoheader, sizeof(biheader));`

the size of the variable (pointer) is only 2. you want to read 40 bytes of `biheader` struct

and

`f.read((uint8_t *)data, sizeof(uint8_t)*size)`

should be

`f.read((uint8_t *)data, sizeof(pixel)*size)`

---

The next problem is %d and %x in sprintf. %d and %x read two bytes on Arduino, not 4, not 1. Print the values without sprintf as `Serial.println(number)`

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for pointing that out. It reads the expected amount of bytes. However he output is still wrong. Fname: rot.bmp
Offset: 00000036
W * H: 0 * 1
Bit# 0
Cmp: 1
ArraySize: 0

Comment: Hey @juraj I answered on your comment on the main post.

Comment: Hey @Juraj, I modified the format string so the correct datatype is expected, lu for uint32_t etc. For the header that works fine now. Pixeldata is still wrong. I followed your advise and tried displaying the Pixeldata using raw `Serial.print`. Problem still persists. `Fname: rot.bmp
Offset: 00000036
W * H: 1 * 1
Bit# 24
Cmp: 0
ArraySize: 1
---------------------------
58 0 0` is my current output

Comment: @MatC, did it help?